# Kerberos authentication in Play framework 2.1

Tags: java, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.0, kerberos

I went through the [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com) for rapid prototyping of Java web apps. The project seems to be just what I need for rapidly building a Java based CRUD application at my work. However, one critical requirement is that the app must support Kerberos authentication.

I can't seem to find documentation of whether this is possible at all. Any clues?

Thanks!
Raj

Comment: I'd also love to know if anyone has be able to make this work. It's probably our #1 issue right now.

Comment: Actually, I gave up trying to use Play for my project for this reason alone. Went with standard maven webapps.

Comment: That's too bad. I don't think the Play folks realize that they're losing mindshare because of this.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102113/windows-logged-on-user-sso-in-play-framework-2). You can use the following plugin: https://github.com/SlyngDK/play-module-ad-sso

If you don't want the LDAP part you can modify the plugin to leave that part out of it.